# Convert a list of list output from webscraping to a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I have created the following code to scrape address from a website, which seems to work fine.  The output however, is a list of list and I have not been able to convert this to a dataframe.

I tried using the pd.DataFrame(addresses) but this does not produce the intended output.  I also tried pd.DataFrame(list(zip(addresses))) but also di not get the intended output.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd
import re
base_url = 'https://www.thechristhospital.com/locations-search-results?Type=AdvancedSearch'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')

addresses = []
time.sleep(5)
button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ctl35_g_5f6e70e2_119c_48b6_a627_dbce7ca77728_cntrlPaging_btnPageFwd')
time.sleep(2)
count = 0
while True:
    try:

        WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ctl00_ctl35_g_5f6e70e2_119c_48b6_a627_dbce7ca77728_cntrlPaging_btnPageFwd"))).click()
        count += 1
        time.sleep(2)
        soup = BeautifulSoup( browser.page_source,'html.parser')
        add= [add.text.strip() for add in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'address'})]
        addresses.append(add)
        time.sleep(2)
    except TimeoutException:
            break
for add in add:

browser.quit()
```

The output i am expecting is a dataframe that lists the address for each location.  It would be ideal to have split by name/address in different fields, but if its in one field that is fine too.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below  is a somewhat different approach - a little clumsy and probably brittle, but it does the job and you should easily be able to tinker with it to get it to do what you want it to do.

I only tried in on the first page, so you'll have to modify that too in order to capture the other pages.

```
data = pd.read_html(base_url)
info = data[0].iloc[:,0] #this is where the relevant info is located

#remove irrelevant parts and split into lists
places = []
for place in info:
    place_list = place.replace('Get Directions ','').replace('Hours','').replace('Providers  ','').replace('Services','NA').split('  ')[:-1]
    if len(place_list)== 6: #some entries don't have a second address line, some do
        place_list.insert(3,'NA')
    places.append(place_list)


#create the dataframe
columns = ['Hospital','Division','Street Address','Address 2','Address 3','Phone','Providers']

new_df = pd.DataFrame(places, columns=columns) 
new_df.head(3)
```

Output:

```
                   Hospital                      Division              Street Address   Address 2   Address 3             Phone     Providers
0   The Christ Hospital Interventional Radiology    The Christ Hospital     2139 Auburn Ave.    Level C - Interventional Radiology  Cincinnati, OH 45219    (513) 585-3072  Charity N. DeArmond, CNPVickie M. Dietrich, CNP
1   The Christ Hospital Inpatient Orthopedics   The Christ Hospital     2139 Auburn Ave.    NA  Cincinnati, OH 45219    (513) 585-2493  Stephanie L. Ellis, CNP
2   The Christ Hospital Inpatient Transplant    The Christ Hospital     2139 Auburn Ave.    NA  Cincinnati, OH 45219    (513) 585-2493  Rebecca K. Parks, CNP
```

Comment: Works perfect and I will modify to get the additional pages